# Change in Javascript/CSS not reflecting from CDN

Tags: caching, cdn

I have setup CDN to fetch my images/js/css files. Initially to override browser cache behavior and to reflect the changes in my js/css files, I used to change the version in URL parameters to make it look like a different URL to the browser. Like http://mysite.com/scripts/common.css?v=45.

But after porting these resources to CDN, none of my changes reflect. CDN always returns the cached copy and it ignores the version parameters.

Please help. I am using Amazon cloudfront

Comment: Getting a page without changes is often a sign that are anywhere occured an runtime error. If so, the old .class file won't be replaced by the new one. I don't know if you can do that, but stop your servers, clear the server cahces and restart again.

Comment: You did not get my question. I am talking about CDN.

Comment: Are you sure that the CDN is the problem? Make a simple test. Take or create one file and add a lot of comments into it. Then deploy it. After that read the source code and look for these changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CloudFront have you read:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=261072

It looks like it ignores the query string when caching the object.  This is quite old information, but I've not read anything that tells me otherwise, so you'll have to modify the URL some other way (filename/path/etc).

They do provide an invalidation API.  Using this might solve your problem depending on your release cycle.